Contract Transaction Fails
I am kinda a novice in blockchain developement, I am working on a blockchain powered academic certificate issuance project
Now I have built my smart contract and have it deployed on the sepolia testnet, it deploys successfully, i will provide you with all the necessary codes to show this.
But i am not sure all my functions for my contract is working, they all work on remix though, so i cretaed a test script to test it but here is the error i get:
Error:
(base) ACV % npx hardhat test



  CertificateManagement
    ✔ Should add and verify a new issuer
    ✔ Should remove and verify an issuer
    1) Should issue a certificate
    2) Should revoke a certificate
    3) Should verify certificate validity


  2 passing (516ms)
  3 failing

  1) CertificateManagement
       Should issue a certificate:
     TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/CertificateManagement.js:33:34)

  2) CertificateManagement
       Should revoke a certificate:
     TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/CertificateManagement.js:48:34)

  3) CertificateManagement
       Should verify certificate validity:
     TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/CertificateManagement.js:61:34)

contracts/CertificateManagement.sol:
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

contract CertificateManagement {
    // Struct to store certificate information
    struct Certificate {
        uint256 id;
        string studentName;
        string course;
        uint256 issueDate;
        bool isValid;
        string issuer;
    }

    // Mapping from certificate ID to certificate details
    mapping(uint256 => Certificate) public certificates;
    // Mapping from an address to a boolean indicating if it is authorized to issue and revoke certificates
    mapping(address => bool) public authorizedIssuers;
    // Event emitted when a certificate is issued
    event CertificateIssued(uint256 indexed certificateID, string studentName, string issuer);
    // Event emitted when a certificate is revoked
    event CertificateRevoked(uint256 indexed certificateID);

    // Modifier to check if the caller is an authorized issuer
    modifier onlyAuthorized() {
        require(authorizedIssuers[msg.sender], "Caller is not authorized");
        _;
    }

    constructor() {
        // The deployer of the contract is the initial authorized issuer
        authorizedIssuers[msg.sender] = true;
    }

    // Function to authorize a new issuer
    function addIssuer(address issuer) external onlyAuthorized {
        authorizedIssuers[issuer] = true;
    }

    // Function to revoke issuer rights
    function removeIssuer(address issuer) external onlyAuthorized {
        authorizedIssuers[issuer] = false;
    }

    // Function to issue a new certificate
    function issueCertificate(string memory studentName, string memory course, string memory issuer) public onlyAuthorized returns (uint256) {
        uint256 newCertificateID = uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.timestamp, msg.sender, studentName, course)));
        certificates[newCertificateID] = Certificate(newCertificateID, studentName, course, block.timestamp, true, issuer);
        emit CertificateIssued(newCertificateID, studentName, issuer);
        return newCertificateID;
    }

    // Function to revoke a certificate
    function revokeCertificate(uint256 certificateID) public onlyAuthorized {
        require(certificates[certificateID].isValid, "Certificate already revoked");
        certificates[certificateID].isValid = false;
        emit CertificateRevoked(certificateID);
    }

    // Function to verify the validity of a certificate
    function verifyCertificate(uint256 certificateID) public view returns (bool) {
        return certificates[certificateID].isValid;
    }
}

scripts/deploy.js:
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners();
  console.log("Deploying contracts with the account:", deployer.address);

  const CertificateManagement = await ethers.getContractFactory("CertificateManagement");
  const certManagement = await CertificateManagement.deploy();
  await certManagement.waitForDeployment();
  console.log("CertificateManagement deployed to:", await certManagement.getAddress());
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch(error => {
    console.error("Deployment failed:", error);
    process.exit(1);
  });

test/CeritificateManagement.js:
const { expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

describe("CertificateManagement", function () {
  let certManagement;
  let owner;
  let addr1;
  let addr2;

  beforeEach(async function () {
    const CertificateManagement = await ethers.getContractFactory("CertificateManagement");
    [owner, addr1, addr2] = await ethers.getSigners();
    certManagement = await CertificateManagement.deploy();
    await certManagement.deployed();
  });

  it("Should add and verify a new issuer", async function () {
    await certManagement.addIssuer(addr1.address);
    expect(await certManagement.authorizedIssuers(addr1.address)).to.equal(true);
  });

  it("Should remove and verify an issuer", async function () {
    await certManagement.addIssuer(addr1.address);
    await certManagement.removeIssuer(addr1.address);
    expect(await certManagement.authorizedIssuers(addr1.address)).to.equal(false);
  });

  it("Should issue a certificate", async function () {
    await certManagement.addIssuer(addr1.address);
    const tx = await certManagement.connect(addr1).issueCertificate("John Doe", "Blockchain 101", "University");
    const receipt = await tx.wait();

    const event = receipt.events.find(event => event.event === 'CertificateIssued');
    const certificateID = event.args.certificateID;

    const certificate = await certManagement.certificates(certificateID);
    expect(certificate.studentName).to.equal("John Doe");
    expect(certificate.course).to.equal("Blockchain 101");
    expect(certificate.issuer).to.equal("University");
    expect(certificate.isValid).to.equal(true);
  });

  it("Should revoke a certificate", async function () {
    await certManagement.addIssuer(addr1.address);
    const tx = await certManagement.connect(addr1).issueCertificate("John Doe", "Blockchain 101", "University");
    const receipt = await tx.wait();

    const event = receipt.events.find(event => event.event === 'CertificateIssued');
    const certificateID = event.args.certificateID;

    await certManagement.connect(addr1).revokeCertificate(certificateID);
    const certificate = await certManagement.certificates(certificateID);
    expect(certificate.isValid).to.equal(false);
  });

  it("Should verify certificate validity", async function () {
    await certManagement.addIssuer(addr1.address);
    const tx = await certManagement.connect(addr1).issueCertificate("John Doe", "Blockchain 101", "University");
    const receipt = await tx.wait();

    const event = receipt.events.find(event => event.event === 'CertificateIssued');
    const certificateID = event.args.certificateID;

    let isValid = await certManagement.verifyCertificate(certificateID);
    expect(isValid).to.equal(true);

    await certManagement.connect(addr1).revokeCertificate(certificateID);
    isValid = await certManagement.verifyCertificate(certificateID);
    expect(isValid).to.equal(false);
  });
});

hardhat.config.js:
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");

module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.19",
  networks: {
    sepolia: {
      url: "https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/xxxxxxxxxxx",
      accounts: ['xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx']
    }
  }
};

